# Get index of the clicked element in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

What is the best way to get index of clicked element of an unordered list?

Let me provide an example. Say I have the following HTML code:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: listItems">
    <li data-bind="click: $parent.itemClicked">
         <p data-bind="text: title"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Right now I have the following javascript code to get the index:

...

```
self.itemClicked = function(data, item) {
    var index = $(item.target).index();
}
```

...

But the problem is the if the target element is `<p>` for example, I get incorrect result. So how should I get the index of the clicked `<li>` element? Does knockout have some method for this or I should use jquery in some way?

Comment: You could check if the target is a `<li>` and if not then grab its parent.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I recommend using Knockout's `$index` context property. See example below ([JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sturtevant/Knd6N/)):

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ul data-bind="foreach: listItems">
    <li data-bind="click: $parent.itemClicked.bind($data, $index())">
         <p data-bind="text: title"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
​
```

**JavaScript**

```
var vmodel = {
    listItems: ko.observableArray([
        {title: "Able"},
        {title: "Baker"},
        {title: "Charlie"}]),
    itemClicked: function(index) {
        alert(index);
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(vmodel);​
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using $index instead of $index()

Comment: Where's this documented?

Answer (score 16):

Instead of messing up your binding, it's much prettier getting the index inside the event function. You can get the [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) from the `event.target`, using the [`ko.contextFor(element)`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html)

```
self.click = function (data, event) {
    var context = ko.contextFor(event.target);
    console.log(context.$index());
};
```

Comment: This is just lovely!